# How to get event wise frequency and the frequency of each event in a dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset like:

```
Data
 a
 a
 a
 a
 a
 b
 b
 b
 a  
 a
 b
```

I want to add a column that looks like the one below. The data will be in the form of a1,1 in the column, where the first element represent the event frequency (a1) and the second element (,1) is the frequency for each event. Is there a way we can do this using python?

```
   Data   Frequency
     a        a1,1
     a        a1,2    
     a        a1,3
     a        a1,4
     a        a1,5
     b        b1,1
     b        b1,2
     b        b1,3
     a        a2,1
     a        a2,2
     b        b2,1
```

Comment: Pandas is designed to store information in multiple columns, so I'd have a seperate column for your event lables (e.g. `a1`, `b1`, `a2`...) and the order of the row in each event (e.g. `1`,`2`,`3`,`4`,`5`,`1`,`2`,`3`,`1`...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
# identify changes in Data
m = df['Data'].ne(df['Data'].shift()).cumsum()
# cumulated increments within groups
g1 = df.groupby(m).cumcount().add(1).astype(str)

# increments of different subgroups per Data
g2 = (df.loc[~m.duplicated(), 'Data']
        .groupby(df['Data']).cumcount().add(1)
        .reindex(df.index, method='ffill')
        .astype(str)
      )

df['Frequency'] = df['Data'].add(g2+','+g1)
```

output:

```
   Data Frequency
0     a      a1,1
1     a      a1,2
2     a      a1,3
3     a      a1,4
4     a      a1,5
5     b      b1,1
6     b      b1,2
7     b      b1,3
8     a      a2,1
9     a      a2,2
10    b      b2,1
```

Comment: How to do the same with pyspark?

Comment: @Akshat this should be a new question with the appropriate tag (you shouldn't mix languages/libraries in a single question)

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
from itertools import groupby


k = [key for key, _group in groupby(df['Data'].tolist())]  #OUTPUT ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b']

Key = [v+f'{k[:i].count(v)+1}' for i,v in enumerate(k)]  #OUTPUT ['a1', 'b1', 'a2', 'b2']

Sum = [sum(1 for _ in _group) for key, _group in  groupby(df['Data'].tolist())] #OUTPUT [4, 3, 2, 1]

df['Frequency']  = [f'{K},{S}' for I, K in enumerate(Key)  for S in range(1, Sum[I]+1)]
```

Output:

```
    Data    Frequency
0   a       a1,1
1   a       a1,2
2   a       a1,3
3   a       a1,4
4   b       b1,1
5   b       b1,2
6   b       b1,3
7   a       a2,1
8   a       a2,2
9   b       b2,1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def function1(dd:pd.DataFrame):
    dd2=dd.assign(col2=dd.col1.ne(dd.col1.shift()).cumsum())\
        .assign(col2=lambda dd:dd.Data+dd.col2.astype(str))\
        .assign(rk=dd.groupby('col1').col1.transform('cumcount').astype(int)+1)\
        .assign(col3=lambda dd:dd.col2+','+dd.rk.astype(str))
    return dd2.loc[:,['Data','col3']]

df1.assign(col1=df1.ne(df1.shift()).cumsum()).groupby(['Data']).apply(function1)


  Data  col3
0     a  a1,1
1     a  a1,2
2     a  a1,3
3     a  a1,4
4     a  a1,5
5     b  b1,1
6     b  b1,2
7     b  b1,3
8     a  a2,1
9     a  a2,2
10    b  b2,1
```